# FFTW input and output display DSP?

Tags: c++, qt, signal-processing, fft, fftw

My purpose is to understand FFTW more. I want to display FFTW input and output data in a graph using qt/Qwt. I have the impression that I do something wrong because my graph is not what I imagine.

Please let me known what is wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qapplication.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <fftw3.h>

 const int N=256;


int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
QApplication a(argc,argv);

 double Fs=1000;//sampling frequency
 double  T=1/Fs;//sample time 
 double f=500;//frequency

 double t[N-1];//time vector 
 double signal[N-1];

 for (int i=0; i< N-1;i++)
 {
 t[i]=i*T;
 signal[i]=0.7 *sin(2*M_PI*f*t[i]);// generate sine waveform

 }

 fftw_complex  out[N];
 fftw_plan     p3;

 p3 = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, signal, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);//create plan 

 fftw_execute(p3);// FFT
 double reout[N];
 double imgout[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   reout[i]=out[i][0];
   imgout[i]=out[i][1];
   cout << imgout[i]<<endl;
   // cout << signal[i]<< endl;

  }
    fftw_destroy_plan(p3);


   QwtPlot myPlot;
   QwtPlotCurve *curve =new QwtPlotCurve();
   curve->setSamples(reout,signal,N/2+1);//plot fft 
   curve->attach(&myPlot);
   myPlot.show();
   return a.exec();

  }
```

Comment: What did you imagine it would look like? What does it look like? Can you post an image, either here or linked to some other site?

Comment: I need at least 10 reputations to be able to post images

Comment: Until you have enough rep you can post a link to an image on a site such as imgur.com - someone can then edit the post for you to include the image inline.

Answer (score 2):

Your input is a sine wave, and you are plotting only the real component of the FFT result, which corresponds to a cosine wave correlation.  Note that, depending on frequency, a sinewave can be completely orthogonal to cosine basis vector, leaving only numerical noise in your plot.

Comment: is the FFT result not symetric ? if its not case , How schould I plot   the FFt result

Comment: Try plotting the magnitude instead of only one component.  For real input, the FFT result is conjugate symmetric, but only strictly real for input exactly symmetric around the center.  A sinewave is anti-symmetric about its origin.

Comment: thank you , this is how I calculate magnitude  magnitude[i]=sqrt(reout[i]*reout[i] + imgout[i]*imgout[i]);

Comment: Should not be there **depending on phase** instead of **depending on frequency** ?